# Finite index subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, modular-forms, modular-group

A complete classification of genus $0$ congruence subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ has been carried out by A. Sebbar [1]. They fall into 33 conjugacy classes with index divisible by $6$. I was wondering if dropping the requirement of a congruence subgroup has also been studied. To be concrete, is there a classification of ALL index 6 subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$? I would be very grateful for recommendations on the literature. Thanks!

[1] A. Sebbar, Classification of Torsion-Free Genus Zero Congruence Groups, http://www.jstor.org/stable/2668773

Comment: It's a straightforward computer calculation using the standard presentation. There are 8 conjugacy classes of subgroups of index 6.

Comment: The reason people look at congruence subgroups for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is precisely because the congruence subgroup property fails. It does so rather spectacularly for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. For example, Luebeck and Malle proved that *every* exceptional group of Lie type (other than Suzuki groups) is a quotient of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try GAP? It should give you all index 6 subgroups. The group has presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^6=b^4=1, a^3=b^2\rangle.$ In general classification of all finite index subgroups of that group is a hopeless task. There are too many of them. For example every finite group generated by an element of order two and an element of order 3 is a quotient of that group. The kernel is then of finite index. And there are lots of such finite groups.

But one can try  to  apply something similar to Stallings core graphs that work for the free groups.

Comment: See [$\S 47.10$ of the manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap47.html#X87FBDA2B815A8776).